# What is difference between fork() and ~fork()

Tags: c, operating-system, fork

how ~fork() function call is different then simple fork()..
i have tried the following code.. in this even child is giving executing the code of parent section.

```
main()
{
pid_t pid = ~fork();
int a = 2;
int *ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
*ptr = 2;
if(pid == 0)
{
    a = a + 3;
    *ptr = *ptr + 2;
    printf("value at a and ptr in child process : %d and %d\n" , a , *ptr);
    printf("address a and ptr in child process : %p and %p\n" , &a , ptr);
}
else
{
    printf("value at a and ptr in parent process : %d and %d\n" , a , *ptr);
    printf("address a and ptr in parent process : %p and %p\n" , &a , ptr);
}
}
```

Comment: `~` is NOT operator. The code here doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Where did you get the idea of using `~fork()` or that there's a separate function called `~fork`?

Comment: Someone is playing a trick on the OP and it seems he fell for it. (But the correct answer is that `~fork`'s return value should be compared to `~0`, a special built-in constant to be used just for testing the return value of `~fork`.)

Comment: @David: `~0` is a little more useful than that, it can also be used to compare against the value of `~strcmp`. Beware that ones'-complement implementations of C might not support `~0`, and hence not `~fork` either.

Comment: Yes, it's good for the whole family of ~ functions!

Answer (score 8):

```
pid_t pid = ~fork();
```

is the same as

```
pid_t temporary = fork();
pid_t pid = ~temporary;
```

You're simply using the bitwise not operator, not another function. Note that this will actually render the return of fork useless, since the child will get `~0 == 0xff` (or another non-zero value), while the parent will get `~child_id` which is, if `child_id` isn't `MAX_PID`, also non-zero.

That's why both child and parent execute the given section.

See also:

- [Wikipedia: Bitwise_operation#NOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT)

Answer (score 3):

`~` just flips the bits of the value returned by `fork()`